# EF on SaveChanges get entity that has specific type from relation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have test classes:

```
public class Human
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Pet Pet { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

in SaveChanges I want to know if coming entities has relation with Human, and get Human entity.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    List<ObjectStateEntry> changedEntries =
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
    .ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified).ToList();
}
```

When I change Name in Pet entity, in SaveChanges only entity Pet has state modified, now from this entity Pet I want to know and get Human entity. I will know that Human was changed to because his Pet has other name, some info has changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might need navigation properties.

```
public class Human {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Pet Pet { get; set; }
}

public class Pet {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HumanId {get; set;}
    public virtual Human {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can reference `Human` from the `Pet` object like this: `pet.Human`

I would refactor my classes to this, but that's up to you:

```
public class Human {
    [Key]
    public int HumanId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}

public class Pet {
    [Key]
    public int PetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int HumanId {get; set;}
    public virtual Human Owner {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I dont want to add back navigation property only for this.

Comment: You need a reference to the Human object to be able to access it.  Without a reference in Pet how would you do that?  If you can be sure Pet will never be created without an owner then you can take the Human reference as a constructor parameter for Pet, but is not really the EF way of doing things.

Comment: Yep you are right, there is no possibility for that